# Computation of asymptotic approximation

Tags: analysis, summation, asymptotics

I have an approximation that I don't know how to prove, I believe it is some simple computations, however, I can't fill in the intermediate steps.
$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}o((\log k)^{-1-\epsilon})\frac{O((k\log\log k)^{1/2})}{k+1}=o(n^{1/2}(\log n)^{-1-\epsilon/2})$.

I know $\log\log k$ grows slower than any positive power of $\log k$, however, I don't know how to simplify so as to compute this summation.

Comment: Hint: $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}o((\log k)^{-1-\epsilon})\frac{O((k\log\log k)^{1/2})}{k+1} \le o((\log n)^{-1-\epsilon}) O((\log\log n)^{1/2}) \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{O(k^{1/2})}{k+1}$.

Comment: @GregMartin but isn't $(\log k)^{-1-\epsilon}\geq (\log n)^{-1-\epsilon}$?  (since $k\leq n$ here) Why can we just take it out as a part of upper bound?

Comment: Sorry you're right, it's a little harder than that :) Separate the sum into two parts, $k\le\sqrt n$ and $k>\sqrt n$. The first sum we can use $(\log k)^{-1-\varepsilon} = O(1)$, and the second sum we can use $(\log k)^{-1-\varepsilon} \le (\log \sqrt n)^{-1-\varepsilon} = O((\log n)^{-1-\varepsilon})$. (Thisi s a powerful trick, by the way: if a trivial bound won't work for an entire sum or integral, split it into two pieces somewhere and try the trivial bounds on each piece separately.)